# Double pairing request with android. Receive two callbacks sspRequestCallback

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing, nrf52

I am testing several phones with a specific App that I can connect to my nRF BLE device. Some phones pair nicely but others do not pair as expected. They display two pairing requests.

- I have checked and found, my BLE device only sends one pairing request which is the case
- When I look into log file of a smartphone that does not connect correctly and I see that we get two calls to sspRequestCallback (see below) and also the pairing type is changed to type 3. This could be the cause of the error but I could not find any documentation of sspRequestCallback on the internet.

What could be the reason we get two pairing requests with some android phones? Do they try to negotiate the connection parameters twice?

Logs from the android phones in the pictures:
[logs picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PFCG.png)

Logs from the nRF controller:
[logs picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRU2K.png)

Comment: I also have seen this with some peripherals. Seems to happen on Pixel phones but not on Samsung phones. I think it is a bug in Android

Comment: I think this bug appears when using "Just Works" pairing method. Instead of a dialogue asking for a PIN or comparison we just get an "empty" pairing dialogue. Therefore its an android design choice or bug probably. (Strangely also with my samsung phone I get the error). Do you know on which android forum I could ask that?